# Regarding Ethernet - Why is the InterFrame gap 96 bits long?

Tags: networking, ethernet, frame

Can someone explain to me why the IFG is 96 bits long? whats the underlying reason for this ? 
I have given it a search but i couldnt find any good explanations for this. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Second result in Google](http://www.wildpackets.com/resources/compendium/ethernet/interframe_gap) when searching for "Reason for Inter Frame Gap":

> The sole reason for the 9.6 microsecond interframe gap is to **allow the
>   station that last transmitted to cycle its circuitry from transmit
>   mode to receive mode**. Without the interframe gap, it is possible that
>   a station would miss a frame that was destined for it because it had
>   not yet cycled back into receive mode.

(emphasis mine)

Technically wrong though; it's not 9.6 micro seconds, its 96 bits - the time represented by 96 bytes is dependent on the negotiated link speed.

Comment: thank you , by the way its 96 bits not bytes :)

Comment: Sorry, typo. Not used to working in bits!